# Triggering event in foreground when background task is running at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a background task in a separate project (dll) for a windows store application.

My background task is triggered when a push notification is received. Majority of the time it happens while the app is not in use. The notification is saved and when the app is loaded again, an action is triggered based on what is received. That is easy to implement with LocalSettings, the application can check to see if something is stored there on load.

When the app is in the foreground, however, I want to trigger something in the actual application. Without constantly looking at LocalSettings, is there a mechanism I can use to have the task communicate with the main application to trigger something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a more specific question, it's hard to offer specific advice.

However, on WinRT I believe that your best option is to use sockets to communicate between the background and foreground processes. A named pipe would be preferable, but that does not appear to be supported on WinRT.

Another alternative that is supported on WinRT is a named mutex. But that cannot transmit data; it can only be used to provide some kind of signal from one process to the other, and there's no built-in asynchronous mechanism for waiting on the mutex, while sockets can be used asynchronously.

So IMHO the socket-based approach is a better choice for this kind of notification.

I haven't actually done this sort of thing on WinRT specifically, just in other contexts. But one limitation that you might run into appears to be that WinRT will only allow communication between two programs from the same package. See [Is there any Inter Process Communication mechanism available in Metro Style App?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ad7f0c02-fd31-48ef-91d1-1cfcf855f688/is-there-any-inter-process-communication-mechanism-available-in-metro-style-app-?forum=winappswithcsharp) for a little more detail on that point. It's not entirely clear to me whether that actually applies to sockets or not, and I haven't tested it to see. It would be easy enough for you to try though.

Another alternative might be to use WNS: [Sending notifications (Windows Runtime apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779722.aspx). For your purposes, I think the "local notification" model would be appropriate. Most of the notification documentation seems to be specific to UI-based notification (tile, badge, and toast), but there is also a basic "raw" notification API: [Windows.Networking.PushNotifications namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.pushnotifications)